# CSV Data Set : Parameterize URL variables in JMeter - wrong CSV file

Tags: testing, automation, jmeter

I am testing backend application, which is in NodeJS and Java technology.

The communication protocols are:

- WebSocket in NodeJs part
- and HTTP in Java part)

In JMeter, I must parameterize URL, to switch between development URL, production and preproduction.

I did it using CSV file.

I created a folder containing CSVs, in the folder where I have JMeter 5.0.

I prepare 3 CSV files.

I have three csv file in folder bin in Jmeter such as:

- development.csv,
- production.csv.
- prepod.csv

My CSV files are following:

```
protocol,   host
http,   10.219.227.66
ws, 10.219.227.66

protocol,   host        
https,  prepod.myprepod.io
ws, prepod.myprepod.io

protocol,   host        
https,  production.myproduction.io
ws, production.myproduction.io
```

and I have set in JMeter:
WebSocket Open Connection
Serwer URL – ws
Server name or IP - ${host}

```
CSV Data Set Config
${__P(environment,development)}.csv
```

and this project doesn't work, in log I have:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File development.csv
>   must exist and be readable    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.createBufferedReader(FileServer.java:424)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:340)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:324)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:272)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     ... 8 more 2018-10-19
>   14:29:30,727 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Authorize
>   success 1-1 2018-10-19 14:29:30,728 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine:
>   Notifying test listeners of end of test 2018-10-19 14:29:30,728 INFO
>   o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File development.csv must exist and be readable at ...

It seems the test is using the default value "development" , so JMeter looks for development.csv

So I guess you're facing this in another environment, in this case you should run jmeter with this additional parameter:

> -Jenvironment=production

Comment: I have three csv file in folder bin in Jmeter such as: development.csv, production.csv. and prepod.csv

Comment: This is exactly error in log folder from this. 2018-10-19 14:29:30,726 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:29:30,727 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv
2018-10-19 14:29:30,727 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line for file jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv

Comment: Where is it ? I don't see it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916804/parametrize-variable-in-jmeter-problem-with-csv