# parametrize variable in Jmeter problem with csv

Tags: jmeter

I testing backend application, which is in NodeJS and Java technology. communication: WebSocket in NodeJs part and HTTP in Java part) in JMeter I must parametrize URL, to switch between development URL, production and prepod.

I did it by CSV file. I created folder CSV, in the folder where I have Jmeter 5.0. I prepare 3 CSV file I have three csv file in folder bin in Jmeter such as: development.csv, production.csv. and prepod.csv

My CSV files are following:

protocol, host http, 10.219.227.66 ws, 10.219.227.66

protocol, host
https, prepod.myprepod.io ws, prepod.myprepod.io

protocol, host
https, production.myproduction.io ws, production.myproduction.io

and I have set in Jmeter: WebSocket Open Connection Serwer URL – ws Server name or IP - ${host}

CSV Data Set Config ${__P(environment,development)}.csv

and this project doesnt run in log I have: Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File development.csv must exist and be readable at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.createBufferedReader(FileServer.java:424) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935] at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:340) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935] at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:324) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935] at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:272) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935] ... 8 more 2018-10-19 14:29:30,727 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Authorize success 1-1 2018-10-19 14:29:30,728 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 2018-10-19 14:29:30,728 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, local)



 2018-10-19 14:29:30,726 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Authorize success 1-1 2018-10-19 14:29:30,727 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv 2018-10-19 14:29:30,727 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line for file jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv 

2018-10-19 14:28:17,339 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv
2018-10-19 14:28:21,184 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Start: Stopping test
2018-10-19 14:28:21,223 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:28:21,223 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:28:21,225 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2018-10-19 14:28:21,225 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Close: /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv
2018-10-19 14:28:21,225 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
2018-10-19 14:28:26,413 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2018-10-19 14:28:26,413 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2018-10-19 14:28:26,414 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2018-10-19 14:28:26,695 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Authorize success
2018-10-19 14:28:26,695 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Authorize success.
2018-10-19 14:28:26,695 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will start next loop on error
2018-10-19 14:28:26,695 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
2018-10-19 14:28:26,696 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2018-10-19 14:28:26,696 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2018-10-19 14:28:26,697 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:28:26,697 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv
2018-10-19 14:28:30,510 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Start: Stopping test
2018-10-19 14:28:30,540 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:28:30,540 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:28:30,541 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2018-10-19 14:28:30,541 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Close: /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv
2018-10-19 14:28:30,542 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
2018-10-19 14:28:34,204 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2018-10-19 14:28:34,204 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2018-10-19 14:28:34,205 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2018-10-19 14:28:34,503 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Authorize success
2018-10-19 14:28:34,504 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Authorize success.
2018-10-19 14:28:34,504 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will start next loop on error
2018-10-19 14:28:34,504 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
2018-10-19 14:28:34,504 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2018-10-19 14:28:34,505 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2018-10-19 14:28:34,505 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:28:34,505 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv
2018-10-19 14:29:25,998 INFO o.a.j.g.a.Start: Shutting test down
2018-10-19 14:29:26,021 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:29:26,021 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:29:26,022 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2018-10-19 14:29:26,022 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Close: /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv
2018-10-19 14:29:26,022 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
2018-10-19 14:29:30,475 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2018-10-19 14:29:30,475 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2018-10-19 14:29:30,476 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2018-10-19 14:29:30,724 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Authorize success
2018-10-19 14:29:30,724 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Authorize success.
2018-10-19 14:29:30,724 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will start next loop on error
2018-10-19 14:29:30,724 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
2018-10-19 14:29:30,725 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2018-10-19 14:29:30,726 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2018-10-19 14:29:30,726 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:29:30,727 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv
2018-10-19 14:29:30,727 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line for file jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:283) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.iterationStart(CSVDataSet.java:183) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at
```

what is wrong, how I must improve this? please help me

Comment: Can you start a new JMeter, run the test and show the full jmeter.log, CSV Data Set config  ,content of CSV file , how you run jmeter ?

Comment: no i dont run jmeter now, becouse i working on this in work - , but I will in work tomorrow

Comment: i run jmeter by console - on mac os x system, open /usr/local/bin/jmeter

Comment: in this link are all logs from run this test   https://pastebin.com/HRSdiKi5

Comment: Seems like you could achieve this with hosts file modifications....

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that JMeter looks for the file in :

> jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv

While it is in:

> /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/development.csv

So to make the path stable, use a property called resdir that will reference the folder containing CSV files:

> ${__P(resdir, /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/)}/${__P(environment,development)}.csv

Put your jmx file wherever you want and run jmeter bin folder using:

> jmeter -t <full path to test.jmx> -Jresdir=/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/ -l results.csc -e -o report-folder

And put your CSVs in /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/

Comment: ok thank you, and project test .jmx I also must be in bin folder?

Comment: sorry, but i dont understand, where exactly i must set jmx file with my test project, in which directory, and what commend i must write in command line, to run project?

Comment: when i run this command in command line
i got 
zsh: no such file or directory: -Jresdir=/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/

Comment: Please check you folders (I don't know your machine) and show full jmeter.log everytime

Comment: ok this run and my debug sampler run and i have this protocol=$P{_P(protocol,)} protocol;host=http, but dont run websocket connerction, and websocket single read samplet and websocklet request-response

Comment: This is wrong : $P{_P(protocol,)}, it should be ${__P(protocol,)}

Comment: IN CSV Data Set Config set:${__P(resdir, /usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.0/bin/)}/${__P(environment,development)}.csv

Comment: ok I done and run, but i finally do one plik csv, in which have dev, prod, prepad and local,. what I can switch between this protocol

Comment: thank you very much for a help. it's run for a development url, but i dont know what I can switch on other url. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933802/jmeter-parametrize-variable-how-to-switch-between-url-variable

Comment: anyone wcan help me, what I can switch between dev,preprod, prod and local
i did parametrize url in csv in Jmeter, but now i am always in development address and i dont know what I can switch on other address.

Comment: can you help me with this also? this ask is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52933802/jmeter-parametrize-variable-how-to-switch-between-url-variable