# JMeter parametrize variable. how to switch between url variable

Tags: jmeter

I did parametrize URL variable in JMeter.
I did this by .csv file.
I have one .csv file, in which I have protocol, host and port;
in protocol I have dev, preprod, prod and local,
and I want to switch between dev, preprod, prod and local.

My CSV file is following:

```
protocol    host           port  
dev    dev.mycom.io         80  
preprod preprod.mycom.io    80   
prod    prod.mycom.io       80  
localDev    local.mycom.com 8080
```

What can I switch between this address?
What command must I write in command line?
And what can I check protocol?

Comment: anyone wcan help me, what I can switch between dev,preprod, prod and local
i did parametrize url in csv in Jmeter, but now i am always in development address and i dont know what I can switch on other address.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through user defined variables if you want:

Name:HOST   Value:${__P(HOST,local.mycom.com)}

Name: PORT Value: ${__P(PORT,8080)}

This will default the HOST to local.mycom.com and PORT to 8080, if no command line parameters are passed, you can then pass the new HOST and PORT in when running the test via the command line using:
-JHOST=dev.mycom.io -JPORT=80

Your test would then point to dev.mycom.io:80

However, this does not satisfy your requirement to use a csv.